# @class @synthesize useablility

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, synthesize

Ok, I have class, that I create for my Core Data

```
LoginPass.h
```

Then I have First class

```
FirstClass.h
```

And then I need use this classes in SecondClass, where I declare them with @class. Heder file

```
SecondClass.h
...
@class FirstClass;
@class LoginPass;
...
    @interface SecondClass : UIViewController
  {
   ......
  }
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstClass *fromFirstClass;
@property (strong, nonatomic) LoginPass *myEntity;
...
@end
```

And in .m file

```
#import "SecondClass.h"
#import "FirstClass.h"
#import "LoginPass.h"
@implementation SecondClass
...
@synthesize fromFirstClass = _fromFirstClass;
@synthesize myEntity = _myEntity;
...
```

Ok, I can make some mistakes in code, sry for it.
I really don't know and now don't interesting why I need write

```
 @synthesize myEntity = _myEntity;
```

but not

```
 @synthesize myEntity;
```

But I have another question. Why I can use then in my code

```
 self.fromFirstClass
```

But I cann't use

```
 self.myEntity
```

Xcode give me an error and say me that I should use

```
 self._myEntity
```

What the difference? Why I can use self.fromFirstClass but not self.myEntity?
    @end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@synthesize fromFirstClass = _fromFirstClass;
@synthesize myEntity = _myEntity;
```

These above lines are correct but nowadays you are not required to synthesize.`@synthesize` is put by compiler itself.

When you use `self.prop` you mean you are accessing property.

When you use `_prop` you call property directly.

EDIT:

When you use `self.prop` you call the method depending on lhs or rhs of =(assignment) :

```
-(NSString *)prop; //gets called when you use myName=self.prop;
```

and/or

```
-(void)setProp; //gets called when you use self.prop=@"master";
```

On the other side, if you try to use `self._myEntity` then it will look for method name having `_` which is not there, resulting in Error.

Comment: Thank you, it's remains to understand for me, what give to me "accessing property" and "directly calling property" =)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing *instance variables* which are variables parts of an object structure, and *properties* which are really *methods* to set and get a value.

When you declare `@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstClass *fromFirstClass;` you actually declare two methods `- (FirstClass *)fromFirstClass` and `- (void)setFromFirstClass:(FirstClass *)aFirstClass`.

When you use the dot syntax `FirstClass *classA = self.fromFirstClass;`, you actually call a method, it is equivalent to `FirstClass *classA = [self fromFirstClass];`. In the same way, if you write `self.fromFirstClass = classB;`, you actually call: `[self setFromFirstClass:classB];`.

If you use the name of an instance variable directly inside an object method, you access this variable.

Now, when you write `@synthesize fromFirstClass;` in the modern runtime, you let the compiler create a instance variable with the same name `fromFirstClass` and write the two methods `- (FirstClass *)fromFirstClass` and `- (void)setFromFirstClass:(FirstClass *)aFirstClass` that will get and set the instance variable.

If you write `@synthesize fromFirstClass = _fromFirstClass;`, the same thing happens, except the name of the instance variable which is created has an underscore in front of it.

Finally, in the more recent versions of the compiler, if you don't write anything, the default behavior is to `@synthesize fromFirstClass = _fromFirstClass` automatically for you.

Comment: But why I need use self._myEntity instead of self.myEntity I don't understand =(

Comment: Either you write `@synthesize myEntity;` and then you can access `self.myEntity` (method), `[self myEntity]` (method), `entity` (ivar), or `self->entity` (ivar). Or you write `@synthesize myEntity = _myEntity` (same as writing nothing in recent compiler), and you can access `self.myEntity` (method), `[self myEntity]` (method), `_entity` (ivar), or `self->_entity` (ivar). From the code you posted, `self._entity` is not a valid option (that means you would have methods with the underscore).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler would add

```
@synthesize myEntity = _myEntity;
```

if you omit the `@synthesize` totally.

However, you could use as well

```
@synthesize myEntity;
```

The key difference is that in the first case, your local variable is called `_myEntity` while the getter is myEntity and the setter is setMyEntity. So from external you would access yourObject.myEntity either for setting or getting the value. The compiler will take care, that the setter and getter is called. You do not access the prperty directly. 
`[yourObject.myEntity = value]` ist identical to `[yourObject setMyEntity:value]` as well as `value = yourObject.myEntity` is identical to `value = [yourObject myEntity]`.

So far from accessing properties or their getter and setter from outside. From inside your class you may think that `self.myEntity = value` is identical to `myEntity = value` (for the second case). But it is NOT. `self.myEntity` calls the setter (or getter). This is important especially for the getter becaus that comes with important memory management for free - with or without ARC. While `myEntity = value` directly accesses the property.

And here comes the _ and its key advantage (imho). If you use the _ notation then the property is called `_myValue`. Doing so it is explicitely clear for you and the readers of your code when the actual property is accessed directly and when the getter and setter are used.